# Makie boxplot width is ignored if only one boxplot

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I am using `CairoMakie` to plot a boxplot. The argument `width` in `boxplot` seems to work only if there are 2 or more boxplots to plot, but ignored if there is only one boxplot. For instance,

```
using CairoMakie

xs = rand(1:2, 1000)
ys = randn(1000)

boxplot(xs, ys; width=0.2)
current_figure()
```

correctly gives a slim boxplot look:

[image]

but doing this:

```
using CairoMakie

xs = rand(1:1, 1000)
ys = randn(1000)

boxplot(xs, ys; width=0.2)
current_figure()
```

instead gives a wide boxplot regardless what value I give to the `width` argument:

[image]

Is this a bug? Any workarounds so that plotting only 1 boxplot also gives me a slim boxplot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both plots actually use the same width, in that the boxes take up the same x-axis range in both. You can see that the extent of the box is from 0.90 to 1.10 in the second plot - so it spans the `0.2` width that you've asked for.

What's different is that, since the second plot only has one data point, the (automatically chosen) visual span of the x-axis is much smaller. At a glance, the first plot seems to be showing from x = 0.8 to 2.2, so the 0.2 width is relatively slim. The second plot is only showing from something like 0.89 to 1.11, so a 0.2 width is actually a big chunk of that.

To make the box visually slim in the second plot, you can set the x-axis limits with `xlims!`:

```
boxplot(xs, ys; width=0.2)
xlims!(0, 2)
current_figure()
```

[image: boxplot with x limits 0 to 2]

Comment: Thank you for this! Previously, I was using Gadfly, and it allows me to change the boxplot width even if it was just for one boxplot.